# Tomcat localhost failed to start

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I was creating new servlet for my project and suddenly i can't run anymore on the tomcat server.

I try to open other project that that is finish and good but will also give the same error. try to create new server and it return the same error

Here is the error from console log

```
Dec 02, 2018 5:33:50 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context}Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Test' did not find a matching property.
```

https://pastebin.com/6NpYR5tq

Comment: Apparently It happen when I add a new servlet in the project

Comment: The root error from the log is "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [mosque.controller.EventController] and [mosque.controller.FeeController] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/EventController] which is not permitted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same mapping for two servlet, which of course is not allowed.

The servlets EventController and FeeController are both mapped to the url /EventController

Either check your design and rename the servlets mapping correct or Google servlet filter chain for another approach.

Show us your web.xml (you can generate one in eclipse if its missing)